# Некорректная работа AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, dialogfragment, android-alarm-manager

Необходимо реализовать такую функциональность : раз в день (вне зависимости от того запущено мое приложение или же нет ) пользователь должен получать уведомление (DialogFragment) с определенной информацией ( рандомной ). Для этого я использую класс AlarmManager( ниже приведу мой код), но я не могу самостоятельно разобраться что именно я делаю неправильно.

В моем случае поведение уведомлений таково: 1) если я установлю,например, время на 9:30 следующего дня, уведомление отработает, но не отработает повторно еще через день. 2) если убрать приложение из таска, оповещение вероятней всего не отработает вовсе. 3) если оповещение уже отработало и я снова запущу приложение-  уведомление прийдет снова ( я думаю, потому что уже указывается прошедшее время). 
Описанное выше - это то что первым пришло в голову. В общем говоря, оповещения живут своей жизнью, а мне необходимо это исправить  и наладить их работу таким образом, дабы получать по уведомлению в день вне зависимости от того запущено приложение или нет.

Мой код :

**Манифест**

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.my_package.daily_notification.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote" />
```

Манифест не содержит никаких пермишенов связанных с этой функциональностью.

**NotificationUtils.class**

```
public void showAlertDilog() {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarmTime(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

private long setAlarmTime() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 33);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

**class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver**

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        alarmIntent.setClass(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
    }
```

**NotificationActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        NotificationDialog nd = new NotificationDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            randomQuestion = savedInstanceState.getString(Constants.SAVED_DATA);
        } else {
            randomQuestion = getRandomQuestion();
        }
        bundle.putString(TAG, randomQuestion);
        nd.setArguments(bundle);
        nd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constants.DIALOG_TAG);
    }
```

Пытаюсь использовать команду `adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt` дабы посмотреть перечень запланированных задач. мой dump.txt показывает что-то такое :
http://joxi.ru/D2PKBXnSdaM9Lm.jpg

К слову, уже 16:35 а `AlarmManager` еще не отработал... 
16:38:56 - наконец то получаю уведомление

Подскажите, как пофиксить данную сложность. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1) Скорей всего это из-за того, что на разные версии андройда intent регистрируется по-разному. Попробуйте изменить на:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarmTime(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarmTime(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            }
```

2) Добавьте `intent-filter` в ваш ресивер:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.my_package.daily_notification.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote" >
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3) Такое происходит из-за того что pendingIntent вы зарегистрировали не с уникальным айдишником (второй параметр)

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,0);
```

И после отработки он не удаляется. И когда запускаете приложение, он висит в списке грядущих алярмов, сравнивается по времени, думает что запаздал, и срабатывает по новой.

Comment: -исправил все вышеописанное. не знаю как насчет работоспособности всех моментов, но когда я только что запустил приложение с таймером установленным на 16:33, мне тут же пришло уведомление. (предварительно второй параметр PendingIntent заменил на   Constants.PENDINGINTENT_REQUEST_CODE= 25123;)
Значит дело не в этом
Может имело бы смысл как то в календаре добавлять +1 день,если будильник сегодня уже отработал? Если это имеет смысл , то как правильно это сделать? )

Comment: @Jackky777, по последнему - установите календарь в текущее время, установите требуемое время. Проверьте, что оно уже прошло относительно текущего и если да, то прибавьте к нему день. Теперь устанавливайте.